# How to pass a submit variable from a view script to exactly the same script to reload it?

Tags: forms, codeigniter, variables, submit

I got a script with some thumbnails in it and one big video and want to load the video of the clicked thumbnail (the thumbnail is a submit button). Therefore i want to pass the clip id via submit button so that the site will reload again (but with the passed variable: `if isset($_POST...`).

If I use **FILE**, $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] or $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] it doesn't work. But I don't wanna pass the variable to the controller but to that specific view script. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. If you use `echo '<form action="' . base_url() . $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] . '" method="post">';` the value variable is passed to the current script. :)